# Store Access Key ID and Secret Access Key to disk using golang aws sdk

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I am trying to persist aws credentials to disk using the AWS SDK for GO. I want these credentials to get stored in the standard file used in the credential chain.

The credentials themselves are user-supplied. They enter their Access Key ID and Secret Access Key. Those are what I want to persist to disk.

I could create this file myself, but I would prefer to let the SDK do it. The SDK will know the rules of the cred chain better than I do, and anytime the rules change, the SDK will handle it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The format is basic:

[default]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key =

On Windows the file is %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials
On Linux $HOME/.aws/credentials

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but there are more rules than that that the AWS cli uses. For instance, you can set AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE env var which changes what keys you use, you can set an  env var to control the credentials file location, you can set an env var to control the keys and tokens themselves, and more. I would rather let the library keep track of the rules rather than my own application and let the library manage the credentials

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot control what the CLI does. If you want to ensure that the CLI and your Go apps use the same credentials, you have multiple options. You could only use environment variables; unset all related environment variables and only use the default credential file.

Comment: That makes sense, but the documentation suggests that the SDK understands the same rules as the CLI and operates on those rules: [Session doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/). Like, when you create a NewSession without specifying any overrides, it knows what creds to use. That doesn't matter anyway, the SDK doesn't have the ability to add creds.